# Matriz con subloques en Java

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas,tengo un problema con una matriz en java, el tema es que tengo que hacer una matriz 10X10 donde dentro de esta tiene distintos subloques todo el borde exterior es el bloque A, y el interior menos las 16 celdas centrales es el bloque B , esas 16 celdas centrales deberían ser eliminadas ya que no se pueden usar, pero no se como hacerlo una vez que creo la matriz no se como referenciar cada subloque con una variable char que represente el bloque A y el bloque B . Tampoco se como eliminar esas celdas internas. Lo que tengo que representar es tal cual la imagen , siendo el bloque de color naranja oscuro el bloque A y el bloque de naranja claro el bloque B y el bloque negro ese es el que no tengo que considerar, ya que se trata de celdas de prisioneros y el bloque negro es el patio interno por lo tanto no debe ser tomado en cuenta . 
No se si es mejor definir Bloque como otra clase ya que tengo la clase Carcel y 
Prisionero , o seria mejor bloque ponerlo como atributo de Celda, pero lo que si tengo que tener diferenciados tanto el bloque A como el bloque B

Comment: trato de entender lo que pides pero no lo hago con claridad...puedes editar la pregunta y poner un ejemplo creo puedo ayudar salu2

Comment: Hola Alex sii voy a poner una imagen de la matriz como seria con los subloques , para que se pueda entender mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te refieres a esto:

```
String[][] matriz = new String[10][10];


    for(int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length;j++){
            if(i==0||i==matriz.length-1||j==0 ||j==matriz[0].length-1){
                matriz[i][j] = "A";
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j]);
            }else if(!((i>=3&&i<=6)&&(j>=3&&j<=6))){
                matriz[i][j] = "B";
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j]);
            }else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

El resultado es:

AAAAAAAAAA
ABBBBBBBBA
ABBBBBBBBA
ABB ( PATIO ) BBA
ABB ( PATIO ) BBA
ABB ( PATIO ) BBA
ABB ( PATIO ) BBA
ABBBBBBBBA
ABBBBBBBBA
AAAAAAAAAA

Una matriz és un contenedor de valores, si no quieres que se guarden valores en una posición guardalos en otra, pero eliminar un "bloque" unicamente por que no te sirve no es la mejor idea, ya que es muy posible que necesites renovar ese código en el futuro.

En este caso lo que he hecho es ignorar los bloques en el centro.

Comment: Hola Luis , muchas gracias por tu respuesta , me refería a algo parecido solo que el bloque que no debo utilizar es el central , coloque una imagen en la descripción para que pueda entenderse mejor . Muchas Gracias

Comment: Otra cosa es que tengo que referenciar a cada bloque con la letra que le corresponde , sea A o sea B , pero dentro de cada posición de la matriz debo colocar a un prisionero.

Comment: No sé si lo entendi bien, pero creo que te refieres a que en vez de que la "B" este en el centro, que en el centro sea "el espacio en blanco", en ese caso sería lo mismo que mi ejemple pero en el ese debería decir  'if(!((i>=3&&i<=6)&&(j>=3&&j<=6)))' que representaria la parte que puse como espacios con la letra B y el espacio centrar como un espacio vacio.

Comment: Lo acabo de actualizar para que veas como quedaría.